# Mimicking Android Home screen icons in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to find a way to recreate the precise form of home screen icons on Android - like the ones shown below -

[image]

using just CSS3.  My best effort thus far has been playing with the ::before pseudo-element as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34m0yyn0/). Something along the lines of

```
.ospn:before
{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:-1;
 background-color:aqua;
 height:55px;
 width:60px;
 left:-6px;
 top:-2px;
 border-radius:40px; 
 content:'';
}

.ospn
{
 background-color:aqua;
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 background-size:32px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 border-radius:8px;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px;
 position:relative;
 }
```

The result is far from perfect.

I hope that someone here might be able to suggest a better approach.  Rounding corners with CSS is trivial.  However, creating the "barrel distortion" effect appears to be quite difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some calculated and statice values....
This shape felt somewhat close, although not sure if could be much useful due to too much CSS applied just for a single icon.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.icon-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
}
.icon-wrap > div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 58px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 15px/30px;
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f7f7f7', endColorstr='#e5e5e5', GradientType=0);
}
.icon-wrap > div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 59px;
  width: 48px;
  left: 5px;
  top: -5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 30px/15px;
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f7f7f7', endColorstr='#e5e5e5', GradientType=0);
}
.icon-wrap > div > img {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: -60px;
  left: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrap">
  <div>
    <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whatsapp-logo-PNG-Transparent.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <div>
    <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whatsapp-logo-PNG-Transparent.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div></div>

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <div>
    <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whatsapp-logo-PNG-Transparent.png" />
  </div>
</div>


<div class="icon-wrap">
  <div>
    <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whatsapp-logo-PNG-Transparent.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** Used the same image from another answer here :P

**EDIT**: added a bit of gradient

Comment: Thank you!  This is a good effort.  I managed to do something similar by combining ::before and ::after pseudo-classes to "barrel out" the vertical & horizontal faces.  There is much experiment involved.  I would still like to see what turns up from others here.  In the end, as you say, it might be just too much CSS for the trouble - possibly with a performance hit

Comment: Exactly!! If same solution i wanted i would just go for some png image which had that shape and put the icon in it

Comment: Added a litle gradient.. if that makes it look more close

Comment: Thanks!  I am going to use your solution.  Whilst the issues with complex CSS might well be true my reason for seeking this approach is that I want to be able to control the look & feel of the icons on-the-go, particularly when the app in question dynamically changes its background - easier to do when there is only a bit of CSS to manipulate rather than an image to change.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use a (Samsung-style) SVG and add a background-image.

```css
svg {
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 447.77 446.21">
 <defs>
   <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="105%" height="105%">
     <image xlink:href="https://placezombie.com/640x360" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" width="105%" height="105%"/>             
   </pattern>
 </defs>
 <path d="M20.64,139.81c15.14-73,61.75-113.7,134.45-126a470.57,470.57,0,0,1,161.14.26c74.86,13.18,119.85,56.23,134.19,130.36a444.84,444.84,0,0,1-.17,172.42c-15.33,72.52-63.14,117.29-135.57,129.53a470.63,470.63,0,0,1-161.15-.25C78.68,433,33.48,387.76,19.15,313.63,7.51,256,8.63,197.69,20.63,139.81Z" transform="translate(-11 -7)" fill="url(#img1)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not a full answer**, but *might* get you closer.

```css
#shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 65% / 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
#shape:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 2% / 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my effort:

HTML:

```
<div class="icon-whatsapp"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #333;
}
.icon-whatsapp {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #eff0f1;
  background-image: url('http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whatsapp-logo-PNG-Transparent.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border:5px solid #eff0f1;
  border-radius: 38%/38%;
}
```

[image]

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/34m0yyn0/1/

Comment: just thought, no need for the "38% / 38%" you can just say 38%

Comment: Thank you.  The result you get is nice but not quite on target - you will notice that the sides of your icon are straight lines. The ones in my screenshot  have a "barrel bulge".  It is getting that bit which is difficult.

Comment: @DroidOS how about this, can tweak the % on the radius, im just short on time https://jsfiddle.net/34m0yyn0/3/

Comment: Welp that helped